# How can i forbid swipe gesture on a specific div?

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, web-applications, html-framework-7

I'm developing a mobile cross platform web app using Framework7 and phonegap build, in a contacts page i embedded a google map view.
In all the pages a side panel can be opened with the swipe right gesture.
I would like to pan through the map freely without opening the side panel, how can i reach this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can change option dynamicly like this:

```
myApp.params.swipePanel = false;
```

so you can do this:

```
$$(document).on('pageAfterAnimation', function (e) {
    page = e.detail.page;
    if (page.name === 'pageWithGoogleMap') {
        myApp.params.swipePanel = false;
    } else {
        myApp.params.swipePanel = 'left';
    }
});
```

there is a lot of other way to do this choose the best for you needs

Comment: thanks for the answer, this will make the swipe to the panel disabled on the whole page, i would like to disable that gesture only if it is executed on the map div. Suggestions on how to search other ways ?